# Consuming multiple data files from ES Cluster in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-4, kibana-5

Is it possible to consume multiple data files from an Elasticsearch cluster in real-time to create a visualization in a Kibana dashboard?

I am expecting multiple ndjson files and everytime I receive a new file I want to merge its visualization to the already existing visualization and get a combined result. The query for the expected result is :

```
GET output-*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "Field1": {
        "value": "abc"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "field2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Field2",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "field3": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Field3",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am seeking guidance on whether it is possible to achieve the desired result with the given query and real-time data consumption.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transform, schedule a task to run the query you shared and create a new index with the expected result.

[Elasticsearch Transform](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-examples.html)

[image]